# Scraping data from an interactive graph from a website

Tags: python, r, web-scraping, interactive

Maybe someone can help to get data from this graph? Is it even possible?

link to page: https://investavimorezultatai.allianz.lt/?tipas=gyvenimo-ciklo-pensiju-fondai

Page has only native language, hope that is not problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can get the data into a dataframe by scraping it from the page. This is moderately difficult. It requires finding the url on the page that links to the html that generates the plot, then downloading the contents of this url as plain text html.

Within this html is a `<script>` tag that contains some JavaScript variables. One of these, called `dataProvider`, contains your data series as an array of objects. You can snip this object out of the page using simple text parsing, then pass it to `jsonlite::fromJSON` to convert it into an R dataframe:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

dat <- 'https://investavimorezultatai.allianz.lt/graph_pf_new.php?' %>%
  paste0('fdate=2018-12-31&ldate=2023-05-04&code=y3&s=1') %>%
  GET() %>%
  content('text') %>%
  strsplit('dataProvider\": ') %>%
  getElement(1) %>%
  getElement(2) %>%
  strsplit('\n') %>%
  getElement(1) %>%
  getElement(1) %>%
  fromJSON() %>%
  select(date, aValue, bValue) %>%
  pivot_longer(-date, names_to = 'series') %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date), value = as.numeric(value))
```

The resulting data looks like this:

```r
head(dat)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   date       series value
#>   <date>     <chr>  <dbl>
#> 1 2019-01-02 aValue 100  
#> 2 2019-01-02 bValue 100  
#> 3 2019-01-03 aValue  99.1
#> 4 2019-01-03 bValue 100  
#> 5 2019-01-04 aValue 102. 
#> 6 2019-01-04 bValue 100
```

This then allows you to recreate the plot, for example using

```r
ggplot(dat, aes(date, value, color = series)) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 0.3) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('#023982', '#1ca3d3'),
                     labels = ) +
  scale_y_continuous(NULL, breaks = 8:17 * 10, limits = c(80, 170),
                     expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_x_date(NULL, breaks = seq(as.Date('2019-01-01'), 
                                  as.Date('2023-04-01'),
                                  '6 months'),
               minor_breaks = seq(as.Date('2019-01-01'), 
                                  as.Date('2023-04-01'),
                                  '1 months')) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 14) +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(linewidth = 0.3, color = 'gray50'),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_line(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_line(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(),
        legend.position = 'none')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You! When I run this code You wrote I get error:

"Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK: [investavimorezultatai.allianz.lt] SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired"

Maybe You know how to fix it?

Comment: also how did You get this link to graph? 'https://investavimorezultatai.allianz.lt/graph_pf_new.php?'